# при использование all in one seo title выводятся в обратном порядке

Tags: php, wordpress, seo

Всем привет. Статьи выводятся на главной странице в обратном порядке, а title в как обычно . То есть title последней статьи выводится на первой и тюдю. Как сделать чтобы на последней статье выводился ее title, сохраняю порядок статей?
вывод статей

```
<?php 

// Template Name: Главная

get_header(); 


?>
   <div class=" wrapper container"> 
    <section>
      <div class="content">    
        <?php
            global $query_string;
                $postAsc = new WP_Query($query_string . "&order=ASC");
                if ($postAsc -> have_posts()) : while ($postAsc -> have_posts()) : $postAsc -> the_post();
                ?>
                    <article class = "wrapper_content">
                        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
          </article>
        <?php 
          endwhile;
          wp_reset_postdata();
          endif;
        ?>
          
        <div class="pagination">
          <ul>
            <?php if( is_user_logged_in() ) {  ?>
                <li class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Предыдущая страница' ); ?></li>
              <li class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( 'Следующая страница' ); ?></li>
            <?php } else if ( get_query_var('paged') == 4 ) { ?>
              <li class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Предыдущая страница' ); ?></li>
              <?php wp_nav_menu('menu_class=bmenu&theme_location=bottom'); ?>
            <?php } else {?>
              <li class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Предыдущая страница' ); ?></li>
              <li class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( 'Следующая страница' ); ?></li>
            <?php } ?>
          </ul> 
          
        </div>
      </div>
        
    </section>
    
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

function

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'function_post' );
function function_post($postAsc) {
    if (!is_admin() && $postAsc->is_main_query()) {
        if ( is_single() ) {
            $postAsc->set( 'orderby', 'date' );
            $postAsc->set('order', "ASC");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Здравствуйте! Проблема в том, что у меня не совпадают title со статьями. У меня первее отображаются старые статьи. Так , к примеру  статья 1(самая старая статья) имеет title 11 (title новой статьи). мне нужно, чтобы 1 статья имела свой title .

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае, мне помогло следующее. Были найдены нестыковки.

Цикл: `global` и `wp_query`:

```
<?php 

// Template Name: Главная

get_header(); 


?>
   <div class=" wrapper container"> 
        <section>
            <div class="content">    
                <?php
                    if ( have_posts()) : while ( have_posts()) :  the_post(); 
                ?>
                    <article class = "wrapper_content">

                        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </article>
                <?php 
                    endwhile;
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                    endif;
                ?>
                    
                <div class="pagination">
                    <ul>
                        <?php if( is_user_logged_in() ) {  ?>
                            <li class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Предыдущая страница' ); ?></li>
                            <li class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( 'Следующая страница' ); ?></li>
                        <?php } else if ( get_query_var('paged') == 4 ) { ?>
                            <li class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Предыдущая страница' ); ?></li>
                            <?php wp_nav_menu('menu_class=bmenu&theme_location=bottom'); ?>
                        <?php } else {?>
                            <li class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Предыдущая страница' ); ?></li>
                            <li class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( 'Следующая страница' ); ?></li>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </ul> 
                    
                </div>
            </div>
                
        </section>
        
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Функция:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'function_post' );
function function_post($postAsc) {
    if (!is_admin() && $postAsc->is_main_query()) {
        if ( is_home() ) {
            $postAsc->set( 'posts_per_page', 1 );
            $postAsc->set( 'orderby', 'date' );
            $postAsc->set('order', "ASC");
        }
    }
}
```